# Hadoop IO Error: Type mismatch in key from map : expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received RegexMatcher.CustomKey

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received RegexMatcher.CustomKey
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received RegexMatcher.CustomKey
```

First I define a Custom Data Type in Map-reduce named **CustomKey**:

```
public  class CustomKey implements Writable {

    public Text userId;
    public Text friendId;

    public CustomKey() {

        this.userId = new Text();
        this.friendId = new Text();

    }

    public CustomKey(String userId, String friendId) {

        this.userId = new Text(userId);
        this.friendId = new Text(friendId);

    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        userId.write(out);
        userId.write(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        userId.readFields(in);
        friendId.readFields(in);
    }



}
```

Then I create a Mapper **SingleClassv2LogMapper**

```
public static class SingleClassv2LogMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, CustomKey, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    @Override
    protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        String regex = conf.get("regex");
        String delimeter = conf.get("delimeter");
        String currentLine = value.toString();
        String tag = RingIdLogParser.parseHashTag(value.toString());
        String body = RingIdLogParser.parseBody(value.toString());
        if (tag != null) {
            if (tag.equals(RegularExpressionBundle.updateMultipleMessageStatus)) {
                CustomKey customKey = RingIdLogParser.parseUserFrinedInfo(body);
                int messageNo = RingIdLogParser.getMessageCount(body);
                context.write(customKey, new IntWritable(messageNo));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And a Reducer

```
public static class SingleClassv2LogReducer extends Reducer<CustomKey, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    TextArrayWritable sum = new TextArrayWritable();

    @Override
    protected void reduce(CustomKey key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable value : values) {
            sum = sum + value.get();

        }
        String compactUser = key.userId.toString() +" "+ key.friendId.toString();
        context.write(new Text(compactUser), new IntWritable(sum));
    }

}
```

What should I do now? Anyone here to help me plz.

**The Driver related code looks like this**

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Regex Matcher");
job.setJarByClass(SingleClassLogDriverv2.class);
job.setMapperClass(SingleClassv2LogMapper.class);
job.setCombinerClass(SingleClassv2LogCombiner.class);
job.setReducerClass(SingleClassv2LogReducer.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(CustomKey.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

Comment: you should share your driver

Answer (score 0):

I were facing the similar issue when creating a JAR using Eclipse for Map-Reduce along with Comparability, and my issue is to print counting in words for 390k numbers in front of the number apart from traditional legacy WordCount program. Here my list of numbers in 12 files which also contains the redundency once.

```
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
```

Which I corrected thereafter and I want the result in below said aggregation -

```
716900482    Seventy One Crore Sixty Nine Lac Four Hundred Eighty Two only.
```

I already developed a maven build tool for printing a number in words and thus added explicitly that JAR to my project.

[image: Project - CountInWords View]

So, Here we go with my program which is similar to WordCount program but different purpose -

```
package com.whodesire.count;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

import com.whodesire.numstats.AmtInWords;

public class CountInWords {


    public static class NumberTokenizerMapper 
                    extends Mapper <Object, Text, LongWritable, Text> {

        private static final Text theOne = new Text("1");
        private LongWritable longWord = new LongWritable();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) {

            try{
                StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
                while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    longWord.set(Long.parseLong(itr.nextToken()));
                    context.write(longWord, theOne);
                }
            }catch(ClassCastException cce){
                System.out.println("ClassCastException raiseddd...");
                System.exit(0);
            }catch(IOException | InterruptedException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("IOException | InterruptedException raiseddd...");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ModeReducerCumInWordsCounter 
            extends Reducer <LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text>{
        private Text result = new Text();

        //This is the user defined reducer function which is invoked for each unique key
        public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, 
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            /*** Putting the key, which is a LongWritable value, 
                        putting in AmtInWords constructor as String***/
            AmtInWords aiw = new AmtInWords(key.toString());
            result.set(aiw.getInWords());

            //Finally the word and counting is sent to Hadoop MR and thus to target
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {

        /****
         *** all random numbers generated inside input files has been
         *** generated using url https://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/random/
         ****/

        //Load the configuration files and add them to the the conf object
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();       

        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();

        Job job = new Job(conf, "CountInWords");

        //Specify the jar which contains the required classes for the job to run.
        job.setJarByClass(CountInWords.class);

        job.setMapperClass(NumberTokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(ModeReducerCumInWordsCounter.class);
        job.setReducerClass(ModeReducerCumInWordsCounter.class);

        //Set the output key and the value class for the entire job
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        //Set the Input (format and location) and similarly for the output also
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));

        //Setting the Results to Single Target File
        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        //Submit the job and wait for it to complete
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

    }

}
```

I know this is a too late reply, but Hoping this will help someone also on finding a way, thanks.